# Mac - VS 8.10 - New 3.1 Project - Install Postsharp

Tags: postsharp

I created a new, console application.  Nuget => Add PostSharp =>

> Reading project file
> /Users/jason/Projects/Postsharp/Postsharp/Postsharp.csproj.
> Restoring packages for
> /Users/jason/Projects/Postsharp/Postsharp/Postsharp.csproj...
> Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1... Resolving conflicts
> for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1... **Cycle detected.**    Postsharp ->
> PostSharp (>= 6.10.6). Checking compatibility of packages on
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1. Checking compatibility for Postsharp 1.0.0
> with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1. Checking compatibility for Serilog
> 2.10.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1. All packages and projects are compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1. Package restore failed.
> Rolling back package changes for 'Postsharp'.

Cycle Detected?

Geez, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by naming your project PostSharp and having a dependency on the package of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, you were right, the project name was part of the problem.

The biggest issue was I needed to manually set PostSharpDependencyRestoreDisabled=True and then I had to manually add all the referenced Nuget packages.  It was annoying, but at least it works now.

Thanks!